# Which follower is the most useful to keep monsters from reaching a ranged hero?

Tags: diablo-iii

I’m playing a ranged hero, and I want to do my best to prevent melee enemies from getting close to me. I’m trying to understand which follower is the most helpful for this goal.

The Templar is a classic tank and has skills such as [Intervene](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/templar/skill/intervene), but the Enchantress has a [charm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/enchantress/skill/charm), [confusion](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/enchantress/skill/disorient) and [disable](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/enchantress/skill/mass-control) skills (not even counting [her push-back skill](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/enchantress/skill/forceful-push)) and the Scoundrel has [slowing](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/scoundrel/skill/crippling-shot) and [stunning](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/follower/scoundrel/skill/powered-shot) skills.

Which is, **in practice**, the most useful for keeping melee-ers from pounding me to dust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd bet on the templar, because all of the four ability choices provide tank-like abilities at will. His taunt ability will keep enemies off you for 5 seconds.

Then, as soon as they hit the templar, his Intimidate skill will slow them down by 50%, making it easy for you to get out of range in case they target you again.

His Charge ability will enable him to intercept enemies that attack you, and stun them for 3 seconds in an AOE radius of 15 yards, giving you time to get out of range.

And last but not least, his Guardian ability will make him attack enemies for 300% weapon damage and stun them for 5 seconds if they attack you and you happen to be on low health. As a bonus, he heals you when he uses the ability, and also gives your character life regeneration for a limited amount of time.