# Situations Where Demon Hunter would Be Better with Enchantress/Scoundrel as Follower

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm slowly playing solo only Diablo 3 and just had the option to have the Scoundrel be my companion.  Right now I'm pretty happy with having the Templar since he is acting as the melee part of my party.

However, it dawned on me that perhaps I'm being too close minded about this and perhaps I should also start leveling the Scoundrel (and/or the Enchantress once I get her).  Without spoiling anything, are there cases/situations where it would help to have two ranged attackers instead of just me playing the ranged Demon Hunter and having the Templar act as a tank?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-each-follower

Comment: Also related (if not duplicate): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66330/which-follower-is-the-most-useful-to-keep-monsters-from-reaching-a-ranged-hero

Answer (score 3):

As a fellow DH player, I've used the Templar myself.

I'm now on playthrough at nightmare mode - and I still feel that he's the one contributing most to my playstyle.

I can't say I've experienced any situations where I'd rather have one of the other companions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you feel he contributes to your playstyle, specifically?

Comment: Well, with his skills - he heals, slows, stuns and comes to my aid if I ever get rushed and trapped. He also tanks, which gives me the opportunity to place traps, and get my damage rolling.

Answer (score 2):

Each follower grants different kinds of benefits. While most use Templar for tanking and healing, he also dies fast to elites...when you need him the most. However, in open areas with good vitality, Templar works better for controlling attacks from multiple directions. Scoundrel is better for boosting own damage and also have stun, plus if using a +cold weapon with multiple arrows offers some control on mobs approaching speed. Enchantress, finally, is the better on corridors and against elites, using knockback and transforming them into chicken.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Templar as my tank.  I hide behind him let my twin hand crossbows do the talking.  If we end up surrounded I can use vault to reposition myself.

I can arm him to the teeth and use his passive healing skills to help keep me on my feet.

Being a ranged player, adding the melee npc was a big boost to survivability.

In D2 I normally play a melee paladin and sometimes supplement with some ranged support, so this is a bit of role reversal.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, with the heals the Templar brings and the relatively Low damage of all of them, can't see a use for any of the other companions with any character. Maybe I am wrong here though as I only have a monk and wd

Comment: The enchantress has a good anti-ranged attack buff and her Charm skill can be cute if she uses it right. The scoundrel isn't great, though. He's designed for DPS when follower damage is gutted to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Recruit them all and level any of them and they will all level approximately the same time even if you don't use them and keep them in village for talking and holding items.

Personally I ended with the templar for tanking of the scoundrel for high damage sometimes.

Comment: I didn't realize they leveled together.  Nice.

Comment: You automatically recruit them all as you go through the game.